# Referring to selected linguex examples without parentheses

Tags: cross-referencing, linguistics, linguex

How to refer to selected linguex example numbers without parentheses? The editors want me not to use parentheses around example numbers that are placed within parentheses in the text. Like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{linguex}
   %\renewcommand{\theExLBr}{} %removes the left bracket in examples
   %\renewcommand{\theExRBr}{} %removes the right bracket in examples

\begin{document}

 \ex. example A\label{A}

 \ex. example B\label{B}

 \textbf{Required:} example in \ref{A} (and example in 2).\\
 \textbf{Unacceptable:} example in \ref{A} (and example in \ref{B}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Defining it globally with the \theExLBr & \theExRBr commands (unselected in the MWE above) and adding parentheses only to examples like (1) in the MWE is a very uncomfortable option (there's hundreds of examples like (1) and few examples like 2 in the manuscript). So, I was thinking about a way of suppressing () around selected examples. Can I perhaps somehow use \theExLBr & \theExRBr commands for individual examples (that would essentially give the desired result) or something similar in effect? The file must be generated with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since TeX has no way of knowing if you're inside  parentheses or not, you need a new command for a reference inside parentheses which will "remove" the extra parentheses. We'll call this command `\pref` which is just like `\ref` but will not have parentheses around the number. But since it's easier to add things than remove them, we'll redefine the `\ExNoLBr` and `\ExNoRBr` to add the parentheses conditionally. Since labels are written to the `.aux` file, we need to protect these commands from being expanded there so that the conditional can do its magic when the reference is resolved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\newif\ifparens\parensfalse
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theExNo}{\protect\theExLBr\arabic{ExNo}\protect\theExRBr}
\renewcommand{\theSubExNo}{%
  \hbox{\if@noftnote\protect\theExLBr\Exarabic{ExNo}\firstrefdash
      \Exalph{SubExNo}\protect\theExRBr
    \else
      \protect\theFnExLBr\Exroman{FnExNo}\firstrefdash%
      \Exalph{SubExNo}\protect\theFnExRBr
    \fi}}

\renewcommand{\theSubSubExNo}{%
  \hbox{\if@noftnote\protect\theExLBr%
          \Exarabic{ExNo}\firstrefdash\Exalph{SubExNo}\secondrefdash
             \Exroman{SubSubExNo}\protect\theExRBr%
    \else\protect\theFnExLBr\Exroman{FnExNo}\firstrefdash
              \Exalph{SubExNo}\secondrefdash\Exarabic{SubSubExNo}\protect\theFnExRBr\fi}}%
\makeatother
\renewcommand\theExLBr{\ifparens\else(\fi}
\renewcommand\theExRBr{\ifparens\else)\fi}
\newcommand\pref[1]{{\parenstrue\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

 \ex. example A\label{A}

 \ex. example B\label{B}

 \textbf{Required:} example in \ref{A} (and example in 2).\\
      \textbf{Now acceptable:} example in \ref{A} (and example in \pref{B}). Subexamples \ref{A:sub} (like this one \pref{A:sub}) also work.


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @oliver See edit.  You need an extra pair of braces around the definition of `\pref` so that the conditional isn't set globally.

Comment: Correct! Excellent, thanks!

Comment: or simply keep `\ref` always without parentheses as given in the answer and use `\eqref`